How to Make Circular Space After Collision?
How to make circular space after collision like this?
Before collision:

After collision:

I'am using PyGame

If it's simply the "illusion" you're after, you can drop / spawn a partial circle on the collision point (versus modifying the 2 other objects).

We can better answer this question if we know a bit more about the gameplay you're trying to create. Are you making a game like Scorched Earth or Worms, where players shoot projectiles that explode leaving circular voids in the landscape? If so, you might want to review previous Q&A about how to implement such a feature, as it's something lots of developers have posted about in the past. If you're trying to do something different, please edit your question to explain in more detail.

What are they shapes (i.e. sprites, custom data type, etc)? Also, I see that you tagged this with collision-detection - do you have code in place to detect the collision?
